# Ionic range component not working after building android app

Tags: android, ionic-framework

The following code worked correctly before I built the `.apk` file with Ionic, but after building the Android app, the range component doesn't work.

```
$scope.br1fanspeed= {
    min:'0',
    max:'255',
    value:'100'
};

$scope.br1_fanspeed=function(){
    send("br1/fanspeed/"+$scope.br1fanspeed.value); 
};



<div class="range range-positive">
    <span class="input-label">Fan Speed</span>
</div>

<div class="range range-positive" >

    <i class="icon ion-sad-outline"></i>
    <input type="range" min="{{br1fanspeed.min}}" max="{{br1fanspeed.max}}" value="{{br1fanspeed.value}}" step="1" ng-model="br1fanspeed.value" data-ng-click="br1_fanspeed()">
    <i class="icon ion-happy"></i>
</div>
```

I wold appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you saying the range component works in browser but not on android device? Or are you saying that after you built it, it stopped working in browser?

Comment: Ya Peter it works In browser but it doesn't work in Android device..... plz give me the solution